# Error:"Key ... is not present in table"

Tags: postgresql, inheritance, foreign-keys, constraints, search-path

I have a table with a character varying(12) field in it which is its PRIMARY KEY.  I ran this query

```
SELECT * FROM bg WHERE bg_id ='470370111002'
```

It selects a row from the table.  All looks good.  Then I try.

```
INSERT INTO csapp_center_bgs(bg_id,center_id) VALUES('470370111002',2)
```

There is a foreign key on bg_id that looks like...

```
ALTER TABLE csapp_center_bgs
ADD CONSTRAINT csapp_center_bgs_bg_id_65c818f360c84dc5_fk_bg_bg_id
FOREIGN KEY (bg_id)
REFERENCES tiger.bg (bg_id) MATCH SIMPLE
ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
```

Here is the precise error...

```
    ERROR:  insert or update on table "csapp_center_bgs" violates foreign key constraint "csapp_center_bgs_bg_id_65c818f360c84dc5_fk_bg_bg_id"
DETAIL:  Key (bg_id)=(470370111002) is not present in table "bg".
********** Error **********

ERROR: insert or update on table "csapp_center_bgs" violates foreign key constraint "csapp_center_bgs_bg_id_65c818f360c84dc5_fk_bg_bg_id"
SQL state: 23503
Detail: Key (bg_id)=(470370111002) is not present in table "bg".
```

Why did this not work?!  Any ideas?  Here is \d+ bg...

```
  Column  |         Type          |                    Modifiers                     | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
----------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 gid      | integer               | not null default nextval('bg_gid_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 statefp  | character varying(2)  |                                                  | extended |              | 
 countyfp | character varying(3)  |                                                  | extended |              | 
 tractce  | character varying(6)  |                                                  | extended |              | 
 blkgrpce | character varying(1)  |                                                  | extended |              | 
 bg_id    | character varying(12) | not null                                         | extended |              | 
 namelsad | character varying(13) |                                                  | extended |              | 
 mtfcc    | character varying(5)  |                                                  | extended |              | 
 funcstat | character varying(1)  |                                                  | extended |              | 
 aland    | double precision      |                                                  | plain    |              | 
 awater   | double precision      |                                                  | plain    |              | 
 intptlat | character varying(11) |                                                  | extended |              | 
 intptlon | character varying(12) |                                                  | extended |              | 
 the_geom | geometry              |                                                  | main     |              | 
Indexes:
    "bg_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (bg_id)
    "idx_bg_geom" gist (the_geom) CLUSTER
Check constraints:
    "enforce_dims_geom" CHECK (st_ndims(the_geom) = 2)
    "enforce_geotype_geom" CHECK (geometrytype(the_geom) = 'MULTIPOLYGON'::text OR the_geom IS NULL)
    "enforce_srid_geom" CHECK (st_srid(the_geom) = 4269)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "csapp_center_bgs" CONSTRAINT "csapp_center_bgs_bg_id_65c818f360c84dc5_fk_bg_bg_id" FOREIGN KEY (bg_id) REFERENCES bg(bg_id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
Child tables: tiger_data.tn_bg
Has OIDs: no
```

And here is \d+ on csapp_...

```
  Column   |         Type          |                           Modifiers                           | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
-----------+-----------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id        | integer               | not null default nextval('csapp_center_bgs_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 bg_id     | character varying(12) | not null                                                      | extended |              | 
 center_id | integer               | not null                                                      | plain    |              | 
Indexes:
    "csapp_center_bgs_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "csapp_center_bgs_5e94e25f" btree (bg_id)
    "csapp_center_bgs_c63f1184" btree (center_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "csapp_center_bgs_bg_id_65c818f360c84dc5_fk_bg_bg_id" FOREIGN KEY (bg_id) REFERENCES bg(bg_id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "csapp_center_bgs_center_id_360e6806f7d3fee_fk_csapp_centers_id" FOREIGN KEY (center_id) REFERENCES csapp_centers(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
Has OIDs: no
```

Here is the version:

```
                                               version                                                
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.3.5 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2, 64-bit
```

And here is my search path....

```
search_path  
---------------
 public, tiger
(1 row)
```

bg is in schema tiger and csapp_center_bgs is in schema public...

Comment: This kind of question *requires* that you include the precise table definition (`\d tbl` in psql). And your version of Postgres, and what you get for `SHOW search_path;` in the same session.

Comment: Erwin I have updated with the exact error message!

Comment: So do you have your answer here?

Answer (score 7):

My first guess would be that you are dealing with ***two* different tables** named `bg`. One in the schema `tiger`, and another one in an undisclosed schema that comes before `tiger` in your **`search_path`** - or tiger is not in the `search_path` at all.

Find all tables named `bg` (case sensitive) in all schemas in the current db:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_tables WHERE tablename = 'bg';
```

To understand the `search_path` setting:

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-to-create-table-inside-specific-schema-by-default-in-postgres/9067777#9067777)

To understand the structure of a Postgres DB cluster:

- [What's the difference between a catalog and a schema in a relational database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022755/whats-the-difference-between-a-catalog-and-a-schema-in-a-relational-database/17943883#17943883)

If that's not it, your index may be corrupted. I would first try a [`REINDEX`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-reindex.html):

```
REINDEX bg_pkey;
```

### Inheritance!

I see in your added table definition:

> ```
> Child tables: tiger_data.tn_bg
> ```

Suspecting that the row with `bg_id ='470370111002'` actually lives in the **child table** `tiger_data.tn_bg`. But your FK constraint references the **parent table**. FK constraints are not inherited.
What do you get if you query:

```
SELECT * FROM ONLY bg WHERE bg_id ='470370111002'
```

If my hypothesis holds, you get *no row*. Read the [chapter **Caveats** on the Inheritance page of the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-inherit.html#DDL-INHERIT-CAVEATS).

Related:

- [Use triggers on inherited tables to replace foreign keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469116/use-triggers-on-inherited-tables-to-replace-foreign-keys/8470021#8470021)

Comment: Interesting...how would I test this?  I do not see any tables named bg in any other schema...  capitalization does not appear to be the issue...

Comment: @user3502355: I added more. Follow the links for explanation.

Comment: Sorry man.  Just a single row is returned.  Can't be the issue.  Any other ideas?

"tiger";"bg";"postgres";"";t;f;t

Comment: @user3502355: Everything looks alright. Maybe your index is corrupted?

Comment: Checked that and ran reindex index bg_pkey.  Did not change the result...Also dropped and recreated the constraint...no dice.

Comment: @user3502355: On closer inspection I found evidence in your added table definition that you are using inheritance, which you should have mentioned to begin with ...